# Couldn't resolve the solution for a Java quiz

Tags: java, while-loop

Consider the code

```
int i = 1;
while (<<?>>){
i = i*n;
}
```

What should be written in place of `<<?>>` so that the loop ends when i is at least 34?

---

Update.

I've tried most of your suggestions before asking my question here, but your suggestions confirmed something is wrong.
that's why I've sent the teaching staff saying that it's not solvable since n is unknown and not even declared.
then I got this reply:

**The code in the question is just a code snippet and therefore doesn't really have to show the value of n (where its value is set). To answer the question, you actually don't need to know the value of n, and that might be part of the intention of the question (I'm just guessing here...).
In any event, you can consider n to be some unknown constant. Your answer will still be the same no matter what constant you imagine it to be.
Thanks,**

*Personally, I can pass it and move on but I'll keep trying to till I get the correct answer.*

Comment: Read up on [Java comparison operators (eg. `>`, `<`, `==`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html). These will be covered in tutorials.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of StackOverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: `i < 34` would work, so would `!(i >= 34)`. There are many answer, read up on Boolean comparison and while loops

Comment: It is not a place where somebody is going to do your homework, quizes or whatever for you, but, ok `i<=34`.

Comment: @SergeiSirik this is inorrect. The exercise is to terminate the loop when `i` is at least `34`

Comment: @Turing85 `while (i < 34)` would run until i is at least 34. Im not sure what you mean. Whats your answer?

Comment: The real question is: what is "n"?

Comment: @user3237736 why? It has nothing to do with the question being asked

Comment: What value is `n`? If it's `1` or `0`, then the only **safe** thing to write is `while ((i = 34) < 34)` which will terminate the loop with `i` equal to `34` regardless of `n`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it doesn't ask to make a terminating loop, just a loop what would end when i is at least 34

Comment: @Mitchel0022: How do you know that? What if n=1? Then your i<34 won't help you much, would it? This puzzle is not solvable without further information on n.

Comment: @user3237736 it doesn't ask to make a terminating loop, just a loop what would end when i is at least 34

Comment: "so that the loop ends" in my opinion implies that it will be started in the first place. So @Elliott Frisch's answer would also be incorrect. Again, without information of n, this puzzle is either not solvable, or poorly worded.

Comment: @Mitchel0022 in this case `while (true) { ... }` would fulfill the same condition. If it ends, `i` is at least `34` ;)

Comment: @Turing85 until it overflows to a negative number

Comment: What.. It says "so that the loop ends when i is at least 34", not "so that i is at least 34 when the loop ends". That's a difference. This puzzle is shit imo :)

Comment: @Mitchel0022 nope. The statement is valid for any endless loop since it is an implication where the premise is always false.

Comment: Putting aside the ambiguity in the puzzle... OP, if this was part of a course and you can ask the teacher for help, I would encourage you to do so. If this is tripping you up, you are lacking some fundamental concepts that this site is not well suited to help you with. A teacher could help identify them and point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's multiple valid answers to this. I would say one would be:

```
while (((n=2) > 0) && i<34)
```

This makes sure the loop is entered in the first place (which the statement "the loop ends when..." implies imo), and also fixes the missing information about n (which could be 0 or 1 for example)

Answer (score 0):

Let's make sure we understand what **the loop ends when i is at least 34** means. **That means the loop will end when i is 34 or larger.** You simply need to write an expression so that the loop exits when i is at least 34.  While i is less than 34, we want the loop to continue executing. Consider that you actually don't need to know the value of n, the answer in the `(<<?>>)` should be `i < 34`.

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Answer (score -2):

The syntax for a while loop is `while (condition)`. In this case, the condition should be `i < 34`. The following code should work:

```
int i = 1;
while (i < 34) {
    i = i * n;
}
```

Also, `x = x * y` can be shortened to `x *= y`. The following code would be equivalent:

```
int i = 1;
while (i < 34) {
    i *= n
}
```

Hopefully this helped!

Comment: Please read [ask] and [answer] and do not answer off-topic questions.